# React form submit and "can't perform state update on an unmounted component"?

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, react-component-unmount

Basically, I have a login page, and when you fill out the form and submit data, it goes through this

```
const formSubmitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
  //validation and other uninteresting stuff...

    axios.post('/signin', { email: inputs.email, password: inputs.password })
    .then(response => {
      localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(response.data.token));
      addUser({ id: response.data.id, name: response.data.username }); 
      history.push('/');
    })
    .catch(err => setLastError(err.response.data));
  }
```

And it works, but I get the warning

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
> This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
> To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect
> cleanup function.

So I google the issue, then try adding the axios cancel token, more precisely I set

```
let source = axios.CancelToken.source();
```

Then added the following to my axios request

```
  ..., { cancelToken: source.token }).then...
```

And finally

```
componentWillUnmount = () => {
    source.cancel();
}
```

But I still get the warning. I've lost several hours trying to get rid of this, I'm losing precious time, and nothing seems to work.

Also, for whatever reason, if I remove the *addUser* function, I lose the warning, but it makes no sense, considering that is just a Redux dispatch, and as far as I know, they are supposed to be synchronous and have nothing to do with the local state of the component.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Please don't use profanity here. There is time and place for it, but this site isn't it.

Comment: Ok, but do you have a suggestion/solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
axios.post('/signin', { email: inputs.email, password: inputs.password })
.then(response => {
  localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(response.data.token));
  addUser({ id: response.data.id, name: response.data.username }); 
  return <Redirect to='/'/>;
})
.catch(err => setLastError(err.response.data));
```

Comment: Huh, that seemed to solve it for whatever reason, which is strange, cause I already tried using Redirect in the past, and there was no difference. Anyway, thank you!